# Checking for duplicates in a combo box

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get my code to check for duplicates in a combo box.

this is my code but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

```
Private Sub flavorsComboBox_RegionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    flavorsComboBox.Items.Add("Chocolate Almond")
    flavorsComboBox.Items.Add("Espresso Roast")
    flavorsComboBox.Items.Add("Jamaica Blue Mountain")
    flavorsComboBox.Items.Add("Kona Blend")
    flavorsComboBox.Items.Add("Vanilla Hazelnut")
End Sub

Private Sub addButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim flavorlist As Integer = flavorsComboBox.Items.Count
    Dim flavors As Integer = CInt(flavorsComboBox.Text)
    Do While (i < flavorlist - 1)
        If (flavorsComboBox.Items(i) = flavorlist) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error!")
        End If
        i += 1
    Loop
```

Comment: Use `Option Strict On`, always. This will point out one error on the `If` statement inside the `Do While` loop. You are comparing an Object from the combo box to an Integer (the count of items in the combo box). Double check your variables and make sure they actually contain what you want to compare. Also, the line which inits and sets the `flavors` variable throws an error, as you are taking text and converting to an Integer, which will not always work.

Answer (score 1):

Your bounds on your while loop are wrong, bracket use unusual, and I think that you're mixing your variables up somewhere along the line.

The following would iterate over a collection in a more readable fashion:

```
Dim newflavor As string = flavorsComboBox.Text
for each flavor as string in flavorsComboBox.Items
    If flavor = newflavor Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error!")
    End If
next
```

You may need to use .ToLower on both sides of the equality operator though.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a Do While or Do Until Loop?

Comment: Avoid using `val1.ToLower() = val2.ToLower()` instead you should use `String.Compare(val1, val2, True) = 0` - it is culture sensitive and more efficient